# error handling ininformatica using error and abort

Tags: duplicates, informatica

I am new to informartica.Could you please help me with this requirement.

I have a list of columns with 2 categories .

Hard check: if the column is null then that record should not flow to the target and should be logged in the error table (not informatica inbuild relational one,I am planning to create separate error table using normalizer)

Soft check: if the column is null then the record should go to exception as well as target table

I also want a duplicate check in the error table, I want the column name in a column called description.

I am aware of using ERROR function in expression to check for not null.But
I also want to capture records with duplicates and display the null records.

Example:

```
record 1 has abc,wer column as null (soft check column)
record 5 has def column as null ( hard check column)
```

Error table example:

```
date        id  reason              description
-----------------------------------------------
1/2/2014    10  duplicate record    duplicate
1/3/2014    1   null                abc,wer
1/4/2014    5   null                def
```

---

Sorry for not being clear while explaining the requirement.I have handled the duplicate scenario in a different mapping.

Below is the requirement for Hard/Soft Checks:

Hard Check: Record should not flow to the target table(only to exception table)
Soft Check :Record should  flow to the target table as well as exception table

Hard Check columns : Tarnsid
Soft Chech Column : Date Date2

### Source table

```
Position_id  trans_id      Date    Date2
1             abc123       31-dec  31-dec
2             abc1234      31-dec  31-dec
3             abc12345     31-dec  31-dec
4                          31-dec  31-dec
5             abc 123456 
6             abc 1234567
```

### Target Table

```
Position_id  trans_id      Date1   Date2
1             abc123       31-dec  31-dec
2             abc1234      31-dec  31-dec
3             abc12345     31-dec  31-dec
5             abc 123456
```

### EXCEPTION TABLE

```
Position_id  description         table_name    Column_Name   Check
4            transid is null      Source table  transid      Hardcheck
5            Date,Date2 is null   Source table  Date,Date2   SoftCheck
6            Date is null         Source table  Date,Date2   SoftCheck
```

While loading into the target table am checking  whether the check=Hardcheck in 
expection table then it will not flow to the target.

Could you please help me with the logic of populating the exception table.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to where you are facing problem, for null check or duplicate check? What have you tried so far? Also, AFAIK to check for nulls we use ISNULL function, not ERROR.

Comment: I have no idea what you need to achieve and the requirement seem to contradict each other (`if the column is null then that record should not flow to the target` and `if the column is null then the record should go to (...) target table` - do you need such records in the target table or not?). However, I'm pretty sure that you need is a router that will check the defined conditions and send rows to appropriate targets.

Answer (score 0):

In Expression transformation, you can do something like this:

```
o_check:= IIF(ISNULL(trans_id),'Hardcheck',IIF(ISNULL(date1) OR ISNULL(date2),'Softcheck','No Error'))
v_col_nm:= IIF(ISNULL(trans_id),'transid','')
            ||IIF(ISNULL(date1),',date1','')
            ||IIF(ISNULL(date2),',date2','')
o_col_nm:= v_col_nm
o_description:= v_col_nm||' is null'
```

This will create your output columns for Exception table. Now you can put a router with two groups for Target and Exception tables respectively, and the group conditions should be like below:

For Target: `IN(o_check, 'No Error', 'Softcheck')`
For Exception: `o_check != 'No Error'`

Connect appropriate columns to target and exception tables.